# how can i view the Text file in proper format using output.py?

Tags: python, arrays, list

*trans.txt file contains all in one line from price to description and I wanted it to be separated after every single saved transaction using my output.py*

**I want the solution that when I run the output.py I want that the text content should be separated
properly**

**Output.py**

```py
from transmod import *
result = open("trans.txt")
for line in result:
    s = {}
    (s['price'] , s['creditcard'] , s['description']) = line.split()
    
    print ("price:" + s['price'])
    print ("creditcard: " + s['creditcard'])
    print ("description : " + s['description'])
```

**transmod.py**

```py
def save_transactions(price , credit_card , description):
    file = open("trans.txt" , "a+")
    file.write( "%07d%s%s" %( price * 100 ,credit_card, description))
    file.close()
```

**trans.txt**

```
00002003685754754275LATTE00001267862587458742584MUFFIN0000323786478547854785FILTER
```

**I want to achieve**

```
price : 0000200
credit card : 3685754754275
description : LATTE
```

Comment: Is the number of digits in `price` and `credit card` always the same?

Comment: no..!!  It always changes whenever a customer order something from the menu...

Comment: Then how wud u differentiate between the `price` and `credit card`? They aren't separated by a space and they are all numbers.